# TypeError : Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined, in createNavigationContainer - Animated Component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

After upgrading to RN 0.56 this code gives me error :

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import app from './App1.js'

const routeConfig = [
  {
    app: { screen: app }
  }, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'app'
  }
]

const Navigator = createStackNavigator(...routeConfig)

export default Navigator
```

I couldn't really find anything out of it,

[image]

Comment: The issue is with the `Card` component

Comment: @AravindS Card is a react navigation component. I'm not sure what I did wrong! I should try from scratch I think.

Comment: you error says its loacted at StackViewCard.js...so check there

Comment: @AravindS yeah Already checked, it's react navigation code node_modules/react-navigation/src/views/StackView/StackViewCard.js => <Animated.View>

Comment: As I saw its conflict of React Navigation 2.* with something else! for now I'm using v 1.5

Comment: @Ramyar did you fixed this? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: @IvanCoronado as I said it was about React Navigation, I downgraded to V1 and it works. I don't know exactly what happens but there was conflict between a package and react navigation

Comment: @Raymar are you using decorators o updating the .babelrc with some plugin? My problem is related to decorators, react navigation is working properly

Comment: bebel is 6 and I'm working with https://github.com/anish000kumar/redux-box which uses decorators
for updating to babel 7 I had problem and will go for it